# How to find whether a pthread has pending cancellation request

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I want to find whether for a thread, `pthread_cancel` has been called or not.

I don't want to use some tables and to maintain that. Is there any library function available for this? I don't want to cancel the thread using some cancellation point functions which cancel the thread if there is any pending cancellation request, I just want to know whether there is any pending cancellation request or not.

Comment: Did you read the manpages on pthreads?

Comment: yes, but i couldn't get required function

Comment: From what I gathered there, you either use cancellation points or immediate cancellation strategy, where your thread is simply cancelled without cooperation from the thread function. This is from http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such function available for pthreads, at least not under Linux. Just out of curiosity: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: i didn't want to use cleanup handlers for some reason so i thought such function if any will help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you call `pthread_cancel`, it is not executed immediately. Processor takes its own time to cancel the thread. But, just to mentioned here: usage of asynchronous cancellation or immediate cancellation is not recommended. I faced an issue where my application was crashing during cancellation when using the pthread_setcanceltype() as PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS. I really could not find a reason why.
As far as I know and even I have searched a lot for the same while debugging the crash scenario, we dont have a method to confirm at what point is the thread cancelled.